# Accessing locally running containers within Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to use Docker to run Jenkins and Sonarqube. Then within Jenkins I'd like to set up a job using a pipeline to build and test the app and then run a scan using sonarscan.

My issue seems to be network related, in that within the Jenkins pipeline I'm unable to hit the SonarQube container IP through the dns name. When I manually find the internal IP of that container and put that in the Jenkinsfile I don't have any issues.

Here are the docker commands I'm using to start all the containers (I haven't moved to docker-compose due to WSL issues).

```
docker network create jenkins

docker run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach \
  --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --publish 3000:3000 \
  --publish 2376:2376 docker:dind

docker build -t myjenkins-blueocean:1.1 .

docker run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach \
  --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  --volume "$HOME":/home \
  myjenkins-blueocean:1.1

docker run --name db --rm --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env POSTGRES_USER=sonar \
  --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar \
  --volume postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql \
  --volume postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres

docker run --name sonarqube --rm --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --link jenkins-blueocean \
  --env sonar.jdbc.username=sonar \
  --env sonar.jdbc.password=sonar \
  --env sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar \
  --publish 9000:9000 \
  --volume sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
  --volume sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
  --volume sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
  --volume sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins \
  sonarqube:7.6-community
```

And here is the Jenkinsfile I'm using within the pipeline.
pipeline {
agent none

```
stages {
    stage('Build') { 
        agent { 
            docker {    
                image 'maven:3-alpine'  
                args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'  
            }   
        }
        steps {
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
        }
    }
    
    stage('Test') {
        agent { 
            docker {    
                image 'maven:3-alpine'  
                args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'  
            }   
        }
        steps {
            sh 'mvn test'
        }
    }
    
    stage('Analyze') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli'
                args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --entrypoint=""'
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'sonar-scanner -Dsonar.source=. -Dsonar.projectKey=com.mycompany.app:my-app -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin'
        }
    }
 }
```

}

```
Is there a way to force Jenkins to work with the bridge network I've created?
```

Comment: Can you try without --link and just letting --network to sonarqube container?

Comment: No luck, I'm still getting the same error response
'ERROR: SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached'

Comment: Probably your sonarqube isn't started. Can you check it with docker logs sonarqube. You should see:
2020.11.30 22:07:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2020.11.30 22:07:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up

Comment: Another check you can do for excluding network problems is to use a telnet container such as:
docker run -it --network jenkins mikesplain/telnet sonarqube 9000 

If it connects, then your sonarqube is up and you can access it from your jenkins net

Comment: The sonarqube container logs look good. I wasn't able to get the mikesplain/telnet to work, I got an error related to an outdated shcema1 manifest format. I was able to successfully run "docker exec -it jenkins-blueocean ping sonarqube" and got good responses. I'm not sure if that's equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty the same, the two are connected. Does jenkins log something  when try to connect to sonarqube in the Analyze stage?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, here's how I solved this. My main issue was confusing docker in docker with giving the Jenkins container access to docker. This article, https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/, details why docker in docker may not be a great idea. And the specific issue I was running into is that the internal docker instance does not have access to the outer docker instance.

So the steps I took:

1. Download docker within the Jenkins Dockerfile
2. Share the host docker socket with the Jenkins container's docker socket
3. Create a Jenkins user on the host machine
4. Add the jenkins user to the docker group
5. Within the Jenkins Dockerfile manually set the container's Jenkins user to have the
   same user id and group id and the Jenkins user on the host machine. Also make sure to
   add the container jenkins user to the docker group, and change the docker group id to
   match the host machine's
6. You should now be able to run the container, make sure to use a volume that you can
   give access to the jenkins user and docker group on the host machine